# how do i forward post data to another page in asp?

Tags: post, asp-classic

I have an asp page which takes a bunch of input and posts to another page which shows a review of the submission and sends an email. I need to separate the review and email process.

my idea was to copy the email page and strip the email parts, leaving the logic which generates the review elements from the request object (request items are looped and output by key/value). the user then has a choice to return to the form for edits or finish the process.

so, when the user clicks finish, how do i repeat the request data from the form to the next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use sessions and another is to use hidden fields in the review page and include a form that posts to the next page and you can extract all the values from those hidden fields.

Comment: finally got back to this today. outputting an `<input type="hidden">` element for each request name/value seems to work fine- everything gets re-posted to the next page.